# how to get tomcat log output?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, logging

I have a web app written with the java/spring/hibernate stack, and I have several pieces of code in the app that print out debugging information. For example, I have hibernate's "show_sql" attribute set to "true" so that it shows me the queries it is executing. Another example is whenever an exception is caught, its stack trace is printed out to console.

Now, I have moved my WAR to the production server which is running tomcat 7.0.42. However, I am having a problem getting hibernate or mysql queries to execute, so I need to debug the problem. But the problem is catalina.out only shows very minimal messages; There is no hibernate output or error stack trace. In fact, none of the logs in the logs/ directory show output from hibernate or exception stack traces.

So my question is how do I get the same output on the server as I get when I'm running my web app locally?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're logging to System.out or System.err, fiddle with logging.properties in ${catalina.home}/conf

If you're using a proper logger (you should be!), I would have to imagine you need to fiddle with the appropriate config file for that logger.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate's `show_sql` prints to standard output `System.out`. If it's not in `logs/catalina.out`, either the parameter is `false` or you've setup Tomcat to direct `System.out` to some other place.